# proof of a limit by using epsilon delta definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need to prove that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2}{2^x}=0$$ using only the formal definition of limit. Can anyone help?

Comment: $x^2/2^x$ is a infinite series? I don't understand.

Comment: changed the title sorry

Comment: how can i improve it and why is it off-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First prove that $2^x>x^3$ for all $x$ in some interval $[M,\infty)$, $M$ possibly large. Then use that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{-1}=0$$

A possible way would be to look at  $x\log 2>3\log x$, and use that $$\frac{\log x}x\to 0$$

Comment: why did you use x^3?

Comment: Because $x^2/x^2=1$ doesn't do the job.

Comment: i got it now thanks